# Uploading a file and a string to http then getting the response

Tags: c#, upload

Basically I have a server which lets you upload files but it requires login so when uploading from the client I'm making I need to send not only the file to upload but also the username and password as a string and then read the response from the server. I have tried my best but I get the error "You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse."

My code to upload the image:

```
string ImgFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
img.Save(ImgFile);

byte[] LoginBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password);
byte[] ImageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ImgFile);
int ByteLen = LoginBytes.Length + ImageBytes.Length;

WebRequest ReqResponse = WebRequest.Create(url);
ReqResponse.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
ReqResponse.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
ReqResponse.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
ReqResponse.Method = "POST";
ReqResponse.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
ReqResponse.ContentLength = ByteLen;

ReqResponse.GetRequestStream().Write(LoginBytes, 0, LoginBytes.Length);
ReqResponse.GetRequestStream().Write(ImageBytes, 0, ImageBytes.Length);

string response = (new StreamReader(ReqResponse.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
MessageBox.Show(response);
```

Comment: Why not pass username and password using the `Credentials` as an `Authenticate` header? Leaving the body to be completely binary.

Comment: Because I have no idea how you handle credentials and such in php.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it doesn't like 2 posts? could just concat them and send them at once.

```
void Main()
{
byte[] login = BitConverter.GetBytes("loginstring");
byte[] img = BitConverter.GetBytes("fakeimagedataherereplacewithrealbytes");
byte[] tosend = login.Concat(img).ToArray();
using(WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("someurl"))
{
    using (Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream())
    {
        rs.Write(LoginBytes, 0, LoginBytes.Length);
        //...whatever
    }

}
```

}